# Serial Port not working with linux-x64 in .net core 3.1

Tags: linux, .net-core

I got an Invalid argument exception when deploying .net core 3.1 on linux x64 of VMware for virtual serial port communication.It works well with the same code on windows.

Does someone know how to solve it?

> Invalid Argument
>
> at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.set_DtrEnable(Boolean value) at
> System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor

[Exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5sZX.png)
Anyway, I created virtual serial port pair by **socat** tool.

```
        using (SerialPort sp1 = new SerialPort(portName: portNameOne))
        {
            sp1.BaudRate = 115200;
            sp1.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp1.DataBits = 8;
            sp1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp1.DtrEnable = true;
            sp1.RtsEnable = true;

            if (sp1.IsOpen)
            {
                sp1.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                sp1.Open();
            }

            using (SerialPort sp2 = new SerialPort(portName: portNameTwo))
            {
                sp2.BaudRate = 115200;
                sp2.Parity = Parity.None;
                sp2.DataBits = 8;
                sp2.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                sp2.DtrEnable = true;
                sp2.RtsEnable = true;

                if (sp2.IsOpen)
                {
                    sp2.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    sp2.Open();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    sp2.WriteLine($"Hello {i}!");
                    Console.WriteLine($"{portNameOne} receive: {sp1.ReadLine()}");
                }

                sp2.Close();
            }

            sp1.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like a known bug: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31523

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
Yes, it is a known bug.  I think it was fixed now, I will try it later.